# Gui program made from Java. Hourly simple maths sum

Tags: java, user-interface

i have a program which is part of a simulator i play.

Every hour there is a `GUI` popup.
It has text stating a simple maths question such as "5 + 6" followed by a text box and a submit button.

I'm wondering if there is any way to create a code of any sort which can use to enter the text and submit the answer automatically?

Comment: you must share your code if you want quality helping.

Comment: math question you can create dynamically. 
For example random first number, random second, select random action and connect this elements together. Calculate equalsion and compare with user answer

Comment: Does this pop-up you have, and it's code with you too?

Comment: Hi thanks for the replies, i have very limited knowledge on this. If i add the .jar file would that help you?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, take a look at [Robot](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html)

You can simulate user interaction , mouse movement/actions , key input .

If you want to however get text from screen outside of jre use OpenCV (computer vision), or Cheat Engine (manipulate/read memory, shoud work with jar as well bud im not sure,research first).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer and info! :) i'll do some research